# Getting the file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dilemma. I'm creating a page where there's a file input that's OUTSIDE of the form, like so. The reason is because of design, there's random file inputs on the page.

So here's a file input that's outside of the form.

```
<input type='file' id='image_upload'>
```

I'm trying to get the form to get the file from this file upload above and upload that file via the form.

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type='file' name='file1' id='image_upload_input' style='display: none'>
<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Save Changes"/>

</form>
```

To do this, I'm using Jquery to map #image_upload to #image_upload_input

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('#save').click(function () {


            var image_upload = $('#image_upload').[0].files[0];

            $('#image_upload_input').val(image_upload);


        });
    });

</script>
```

The problem is the actual file is not getting loaded using val(), only the file path. I need to actual file so I can upload it on the back-end. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `.[0]` is invalid syntax, do you really have that `.` there?

Comment: You can't use `.val()` to set the value of a file input, for the same reason you don't use `.val()` to read the value of a file input.

Comment: @Barmar so how do I do it?

Comment: Did you look at the question I linked to?

Comment: Yes, and It didn't work as I hoped. However, I've come up with a different workaround.